# Installing a BMDC into an IBM Thinkpad T41 without one

Tags: upgrade, bluetooth, modem, thinkpad

I have an IBM T41 notebook that came with an MDC (modem daughter card) in its CDC slot. I see many BMDCs (bluetooth/modem daughter cards) for sale on eBay dirt cheap and was considering getting one. However, I've read that you can't just slap any old daughter card into a CDC slot and expect it to work; it's reliant on the BIOS being able to talk to the hardware on the card. I know that one could get T41s with the BDMC installed, though, and I'm wondering if putting another T41's BMDC into mine would work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I threw some caution to the wind and ordered a BMDC off of eBay using part numbers listed on [this ThinkWiki page](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/IBM_Integrated_Bluetooth_II_with_56K_Modem_(BMDC)) for about $4~5. Snapped it in, booted up, downloaded and installed drivers from IBM's support site, hit <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>, and boom, it works! A resounding **yes**!

Though, my T41 didn't have a bluetooth antenna in it since it didn't ship with a BMDC, so I have to place my phone directly over the chip to get them to talk until I get my hands on an antenna.